# Problem with uploading multiple documents in SFDC in Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning, community

I have an issue in regards to uploading multiple document in sfdc,
basically what's happening is instead of 3 different files being saved in SFDC, it will save 3 same documents in SFDC...

I think my issue is with my Helper class.....

I'm just iterating it in a for loop to basically call the apex controller 3x and pass the file values.

my apex controller can only handle one record at a time.

This is my code

Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" 
            controller="PC_Roche_P360_Dashboard_Controller">
<aura:attribute name="files" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="attachmentList" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="totalFileSize" type="Integer"/>
<div class="slds-card__body">
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.files}" var="file" indexVar="index">
     <lightning:layout>
         <lightning:layoutItem size="2">
                <h5>{!file.name}</h5>
         </lightning:layoutItem>
         <lightning:layoutItem size="2">
                <a onclick="{!c.removeItem}" data-selected-Index="{!index}">Remove</a>
         </lightning:layoutItem>
     </lightning:layout>

</aura:iteration>
<lightning:input disabled="false" aura:id="fileId" onchange="{!c.processSelectedFile}" type="file" name="file" label="Upload Document" multiple="true" accept="image/jpg , application/pdf" />
```

controller

```
({
processSelectedFile : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('processSelectedFile');
    var fileName = '';
    var files = component.get("v.files");

    console.log('Filelength -> ' + event.getSource().get("v.files").length);
    console.log('fileId -> ',component.find("fileId").get("v.value")); 

    if(event.getSource().get("v.files").length > 0) {
        console.log('file length -> ' + event.getSource().get("v.files").length);
        var newlySelected = event.getSource().get("v.files");

        var attachmentList = component.get("v.attachmentList");
        //var parentId = component.get("v.recordId");
        var totalSize = component.get('v.totalFileSize') ? component.get('v.totalFileSize') : 0;
        for(var i in newlySelected){
            var file = newlySelected[i];
            if(!$A.util.isEmpty(file.type)){
                    //fileName = file['name'];
                    totalSize = totalSize + file.size;
                    file.src =  URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    files.push(file);
            }
        }
        component.set('v.totalFileSize', totalSize);
        component.set("v.files",files);
        console.log('files -> ',files);
        // component.find("fileId").set("v.value",null);
        console.log('fileId AFTER -> ',component.find("fileId").get("v.value")); 
        //fileName = files.length + ' ' + 'image/s selected';
    }
},

removeItem : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('REMOVE ITEM>>>>>');
    var target = event.target; 
    var dataEle = target.getAttribute("data-selected-Index");

    if(!$A.util.isEmpty(dataEle)){
        console.log('dataEle -> ' + dataEle);
        //var totalSize =  component.get('v.totalFileSize');
        var files = component.get("v.files");
        /*

        if (totalSize && files[event.getParam("index")]) {
            totalSize = totalSize - files[event.getParam("index")].size;
        }
        */

        files.splice(dataEle, 1);
        component.set("v.files",files);
        /*component.set('v.totalFileSize', totalSize);*/
    }
},
saveDocument : function(component,event,helper){
    helper.uploadFile(component,event,helper);
},
```

})

Helper

```
({
uploadFile : function(component, event , helper){
    var files = component.get('v.files');
    var filesLength = component.get('v.files').length;
    var self = this;

    for(var i=0; i < filesLength; i++){
            var file = files[i];
            alert(file.name);
            var fr = new FileReader();
            var self = this;
            fr.onloadend = function(e) {
                var fileContents = e.target.result;
                var base64Mark = 'base64,';
                var dataStart = fileContents.indexOf(base64Mark) + base64Mark.length;
                fileContents = fileContents.substring(dataStart);
                self.upload(component, file, fileContents);
            };
            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    },

    upload : function(component,file,fileContents) {
    console.log('HELPER>>>>>');
    var recordId = 'a0Y0w00000093ZHEAY'
    var action = component.get('c.saveTheChunk');
    console.log('file.name>>>>>' + file.name);

    action.setParams({
        "parentId": recordId,
        "fileName": file.name,
        "base64Data": encodeURIComponent(fileContents), 
        "contentType": file.type
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log('UPLOAD SUCCESS');
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                             errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

})

snippet of apex controller

```
    @AuraEnabled
public static String saveTheChunk(String parentId, String fileName, String base64Data, String contentType, String affiliate) {

    Id attachmentid = null;
    try{

        base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');
        List<String> selectedCategories = new List<String>{'Proof of Purchase'};
        Id docId = createDocumentAndLogRecords(parentId, 'Review Needed', selectedCategories);
        if (docId == null) return null;

        //save to attachment
        attachmentid = createAttachment(docId, fileName, base64Data, contentType);
        System.debug('ATTACHMENTID>>>>>>' + attachmentId);

        //update doc owner id
        String username = Userinfo.getUserName();

        system.debug('username' + username);

        if(username != null){
            User user = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE username = :username];
            PatientConnect__PC_Document__c doc = new PatientConnect__PC_Document__c();
            doc.Id = docId;
            doc.ownerid = user.Id;
            /*
            User loggedInUser = [select id, name, contact.accountid from user where id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
            if(loggedInUser.contact.accountid != null){
                doc.PC_Roche_Patient__c = loggedInUser.contact.accountid;
            }
            */

            update doc;
        }         
    }catch(Exception e){
        PC_Roche_Utility.logAndThrowException(e);
    }

    return attachmentid;

}
```

Comment: Why not use [`lightning:fileUpload`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation)?

Comment: As @JayantDas says - use standard lightning:fileupload - it is excellent

Comment: `lightning:fileUpload` is an excellent solution but beware that it will be uploaded to the ContentDocument instead of Attachment. And using the code as such will lead to head size limit (I got it in the past when lightning:fileUpload was not available).